Installed SCIP from source, now struggling to get a simple example work in C/C++ using CMake
I followed the steps mentioned here to install SCIP using SoPlex LP solver. The last step sudo make install worked and I observe that SCIP has gotten installed to /usr/local/include/ and /usr/local/lib/. Now, I am looking for a simple example that creates an LP/MIP and solves it using SCIP via C/C++ code. This is where I am stuck. Does SCIP ship with an example CMakeLists.txt for a small simple project?
Reason I ask is that this link seems overly complicated as it seems to ask the user to run the whole CMakeLists.txt used for building SCIP itself during the installation of SCIP phase. Quoting from there:

The application can be compiled within the same build directory as SCIP.

That is exactly what I don't want. I want to create my own simple LP/MIP using my own code and then build the application where the executable gets built in my own user folder and not touch the installation folder of SCIP or the build directory as SCIP. From within my code, I only want to refer to include files/libraries installed in /usr/local/include/ and /usr/local/lib/.
In other words, is there any SCIP tutorial/documentation equivalent to Gurobi's example here or CPLEX's example here?

In general you only need to include SCIP headers and link against SCIP library. In this regards, the Sudoku example is rather minimal (target_link_libraries, include_directories). You can do this manually (e.g. hard-coded paths), or use some CMake helpers like find_package (also shown in example). (Depending on your usage, there might be more to link: but this should be limited to the usual candidates: zlib, pthread, ...)
